# How do I propogate Windows Identity without using delegation in WCF?

Tags: wcf, wcf-authentication

I need to propagate the Windows Identity of the current user across two service calls.

Service A (which runs under integrated authentication) calls Service B (which also runs under integrated authentication). I need to identify the user identity which was used to call Service A in Service B's code.

I know this is possible using delegation, by impersonating the User in Service A code and then call Service B from the impersonated code.

However, I only want to flow the identity and not impersonate the user. Is this possible without impersonation?

Comment: do you just want the user name to be sent to the second service or do you want the second service call to be made under the user's identity?

Comment: I just want the username to be sent to the second service or any other way of identifying the original user on the second service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the authenticated user using ServiceSecurityontext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name

Add this as either a header or a field in the downstream service request

Comment: The trouble is that we have a lot of services already written. We could use delegation, but do not want that. The fallback of course is to write code to propagate those credentials in a field. Is it possible to propagate only the identity without impersonation and without using a field or the header for the downstream service? (I know it sounds stupid, but just asking)

Comment: There is no way to automatically send the identity downstream without explicitly passing it or delegation

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the impersonation level called "Identity". See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788971.aspx) for a description of different impersonation levels in WCF.

Comment: I know that "identity" can be used to identify the credentials in the first service. What about the hop? How do I propagate these credentials to the second call without impersonation?